# Алгоритм для программы Python

Tags: алгоритм, python-3.6

> Напишите программу, которая отгадывает загаданное целое число от 1 до 1000 (пользователь загадывает число в уме и не сообщает программе). Угадать число нужно не более чем за 10 попыток. На каждую попытку пользователь отвечает, что названное число больше загаданного (вводит символ “>”), меньше загаданного (“<”) или угадано правильно (“=”).
>   Используйте бинарный поиск. Программа должна каждый раз называть число, находящееся посередине исследуемого диапазона — в результате станет ясно, в какой половине диапазона находится искомое число.
>   Например, для диапазона от 1 до 8 (а не до 1000) это могло бы выглядеть так (загадано число 5):
>   4 (программа пробует угадать, называя число из середины интервала от 1 до 8) 
>   < (пользователь отвечает, что названное число меньше искомого; теперь программа ищет в интервале от 4 до 8)

Я недавно начал изучать Python. Эту задачу я решил, но она работает криво и не так, как должно быть. У меня возникла проблема, что я понимаю, как написать программу, но не могу правильно выразить мысли в коде.

```
left = 0
right = 1000
answer = None
while answer != '=':
    answer = input()
    if answer == '=':
        print('Я угадал!')
        break
    elif answer == '<':
        left = (left + right) // 2
        print(left, '?')
    elif answer == '>':
        right = (right - left) // 2 + left
        print(right, '?')
```

Comment: начинать явно стоит с вывода предложения 500. А иначе на что будет давать ответ пользователь ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В целом ваше решение не такое уж и плохое, предлагаю несколько шагов по улучшению:

Во первых, в вашем решении сбивает то что пользователю ничего не показывается при запуске программы, это решается вычислением первого числа до цикла `while`.

```
left = 0
right = 1001
current = (left + right) // 2
```

Обратите внимание что `right` мы устанавливаем в 1001 а не 1000, это необходимо что бы при "угадывании" захватить число `1000`.

Во вторых, я бы рекомендовал вынести вывод текущего числа в начало цикла, так же для того что бы показать пользователю текущее значение и ожидать его реакции.

```
while answer != '=':
    print(current, '?')
    answer = input()
```

В третьих, после этого можно внести небольшие изменения в цепочку `if-elif`, этот вариант отличается от вашего тем что здесь изменяются только границы нашего вычисления и добавлена обработка некорректного ввода

```
    if answer == '=':
        print('Я угадал!')
        break
    elif answer == '>':
        left = current
    elif answer == '<':
        right = current
    else:
      print('Повторите ввод (>, <, =)!')
      continue
```

И самом конце цикла добавляем сточку с вычислением текущего значения

```
current = (left + right) // 2
```

**Код полностью**

```
left = 0
right = 1001
current = (left + right) // 2
answer = None

while answer != '=':
    print(current, '?')
    answer = input()

    if answer == '=':
        print('Я угадал!')
        break
    elif answer == '>':
        left = current
    elif answer == '<':
        right = current
    else:
      print('Повторите ввод (>, <, =)!')
      continue

    current = (left + right) // 2
```